# Find the minimum value of $f(x) = x^8 + x^6 -x^4 -2x^3 -x^2 -2x +9 $

Tags: functions, derivatives

Find the minimum value of $$f(x) = x^8 + x^6 -x^4 -2x^3 -x^2 -2x +9 $$

The options given in the question are:

(A) 0
(B) 1
(C) 2
(D) 3

I tried finding out the derivative of the function but am unable to proceed further.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) will at least let you figure out that $x=1$ has $f'(x)=0$. From here, you may be able to conclude the number of complex roots to $f'$ ($6$) using [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) to rule out any other potential (real) critical points.

Comment: Although I have solve question below. But next time you will  have to show your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

We can write

$\displaystyle f(x)=(x^4)^2+1-2x^4+(x^3)^2+1-2x^3+(x^2)^2+1-2x^2+x^2+1-2x+5$

$\displaystyle f(x)=(x^4-1)^2+(x^3-1)^2+(x^2-1)^2+(x-1)^2+5\geq 5$

Which occur when $x=1$